# How to extract letters and numbers from array and passing to a string using a function using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, character

I need to pass an array of characters to a function, and extract from that array only letters and numbers; then I should pass those characters to a string and return the string. All of this using a function. I am getting an output warning that the function is not returning the correct value. Say the array was ['A','-','5','/','v','$,'f','4','%','2','3',''], the output should be ths string 'A5vf423'.

I am not sure if I need to declare `arrayInput` or `str` but I think the issue is that I am not passing correctly the characters from the vector to the string.

```js
var high = function(arrayInput) {

  var str = ' ';

  for (var i = 0; i < arrayInput; i++) {

    if (arrayInput[i] >= 'a' && arrayInput[i] <= 'a' &&
      arrayInput[i] >= 'A' && arrayInput[i] <= 'Z'&&
      arrayInput[i] >= '0' && arrayInput[i] <= '9') {

      str = arrayInput[i].join('');
    }
    return str
  };
}
```

EDIT:   Solution:

`return arrayName.filter(character => /^[a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(character)).join("")`

Comment: Is this in a function? As otherwise `return` wouldn't work

Comment: 1) `&&` should be `||`. A character can't be between all those ranges 2) `str=arrayInput[i].join('')` should be `str += arrayInput[i]` 3) Typo here: `arrayInput[i]<='a'` should be `'z'`

Comment: Yes, it is. Should the return be right after ```str=arrayInput[i].join('');```? The function is supposed to return the string

Comment: `i < arrayInput` should be `arrayInput.length`. You also need to group each range. Move the `return` out of the `for` loop

Comment: adiga, you are right! The && should be || (made absolutely no sense, lack of experience coding here), and yes there was a typo. I am trying to figure out how to pass the characters to the string now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `regex` to match if is letter or number:

With `filter` checks each item and check if its letter or number and returns only items that is letter or number.

Regex:

- [a-z|0-9] : includes any characters between a-z or 0-9
- /i : non case sensitive

```js
const arr = ["A", "/", "r", "6", ".", "a"];

function getString(arr) {
  return arr.filter(l => l.match(/[a-z|0-9]/i)).join("")
}

console.log(getString(arr))
```

Comment: You can use `\w` instead of `[a-z|0-9]`, and you also wouldn't need the `i` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Reformat your conditional:

```js
(arrayInput[i]>='a'&&arrayInput[i]<='z'||arrayInput[i]>='A'&&arrayInput[i]<='Z'||arrayInput[i]>='0'&&arrayInput[i]<='9')
```

Due to operator precedence, the above condition needs no brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
function high(arrayInput) {

  let str = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < arrayInput.length; i++) {
    if ((arrayInput[i] >= 'a' && arrayInput[i] <= 'z') ||
        (arrayInput[i] >= 'A' && arrayInput[i] <= 'Z') ||
        (arrayInput[i] >= '0' && arrayInput[i] <= '9')) {

      str += arrayInput[i];
    }
  }

  return str;
}
```